# Sonar Violation : Inefficient use of keySet iterator instead of entrySet iterator

Tags: java

Please refer to the following method:

```
public Properties getProperties()
    {
        try
        {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            loadProperties(properties);
            for (Object key : properties.keySet())
            {
                properties.setProperty((String) key, convertPropertyValue(properties.getProperty((String) key)));
            }

            // Add Config API Keys/Values
            IConfigurationManager configMgr = ConfigurationManager.getInstance();
            Map<String, Setting> settings = configMgr.getSettings();
            for (String key : settings.keySet()) {
                properties.setProperty(key, settings.get(key).getValue());
            }

            return properties;
        } catch (java.io.IOException ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When I change the code to retrieve as `settings.entrySet()` instead of `settings.keySet()`, it's throwing the following error:

```
<<< error: incompatible types
[ERROR] for (String key : settings.entrySet()) >>>
```

I can understand that since the `entrySet` is returning key value pair where only key is expected, I am getting the incompatible error.

How can I implement `entrySet` for the following piece of code to fix the sonar violation?

Here is the `setProperty()` method to which key and value are set

```
public synchronized Object setProperty(String key, String value) {
    return put(key, value);
}
```

Comment: Must you create a `Properties` object? Would it be OK for the rest of your code if this method created a `Map<String, String>` instead?

Comment: could anyone address this issue as well? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476889/sonar-violation-dodgy-write-to-static-field-from-instance-method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Map.entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) returns the type [`Set<Map.Entry>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html). `Map.Entry` is used to hold together each key and the value associated. Since it is possible to iterate over a `Set` with a traditional for-each loop, you can rewrite your for loop like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Setting> entry : settings.entrySet()) {
    properties.setProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().getValue());
}
```

Comment: entry.getValue() - Returns the value corresponding to this entry. Can you please tell me what does "entry.getValue().getValue()" will return?

Comment: @Renga In your initial code, you used `settings.get(key).getValue()`. I rewrote `settings.get(key)` to `entry.getValue()` so `settings.get(key).getValue()` is `entry.getValue().getValue()`.